# Android: pixel quality reduction in Images loaded in WebView

Tags: android, image, html, canvas, webview

I am building Javascript  application for mobile browsers (not wrapped-as-native app).

I noticed that Android (tested 2.3 emulator and Galaxy S device) reduces the quality of loaded images if the image dimensions exceed certain threshold (width above 1400 px or so). This make it impossible to load big bitmap images (2000 x 2000 px) without the quality going unusable.

I tested this by

- Loading one big image and drawing it on the  - I got pixel garbage out. If I draw grid lines using lineTo() on  they have perfect quality, so the bad must be in the image pixel data
- Slicing the big image to 100 x 100 slices and drawing them to a canvas - this is the only method I found resulting no quality reduction. However, slicing is cumbersome, adds extra step to preprocess images and page loading times suffers
- I tested tring to load image with new Image() object,  tag and CSS background: everything suffers from the reduced quality, so I suspect the probelm is the image loader itself
- I also tried everything with CSS image-rendering https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering - no luck
- Viewport tag seems to have no effect to the image loading - the data is already garbage when you try to touch the loaded pixel data. I tried all possible values suggested in Android's SDK documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Tested also Firefox mobile, desktop browsers, iOS: everything is good there.

So, what is going on - Android WebView simply can't load big images?

(smiley of hung Android robot here)

Comment: Applications on Android are limited to 16-24mb ram per process. An image of 2000x2000px in ARGB8888 would use ~15mb. I assume the browser is just trying to avoid running out of memory. Just in case you want to take a deeper look here is the code: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=tree

Comment: My device has one gigabyte of memory and no other apps open. If this is the case it would be very sad platform design indeed.

Comment: Also there is no point here because I can create <canvas> as large I want, but not properly sized images for it!

Comment: I think it's called image subsampling in WebKit source tree: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/webkit.git;a=blob;f=WebCore/platform/graphics/android/ImageAndroid.cpp;h=01fe272dc567a0bd80925a4014edecee50f50b26;hb=HEAD

Comment: Bitmap class it's using: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/skia.git;a=blob;f=include/core/SkBitmap.h;h=91143c1dfc40f4810a22f8965921ab492edbe365;hb=HEAD

Comment: Culprint: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/webkit.git;a=blob;f=WebCore/platform/graphics/android/ImageSourceAndroid.cpp MAX_SIZE_BEFORE_SUBSAMPLE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android unconditionally resamples images and reduces quality if a certain threshold of memory usage is exceeded.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/android-3.2.4_r1/WebCore/platform/graphics/android/ImageSourceAndroid.cpp

There is no way to access the original image data in intact.

I posted a question regarding this to android-developers Google Group and kindly asking to maybe provide some kind of flag to opt-out from this behavior.

Meanwhile, if you are considering developing HTML5 web apps and you might use big images, you simply need to preprocess them on the server-side by slicing, send in smaller images to the device and then reconstuct the original image using  or putting many  tags inside a container element.

Another option would be load image "manually" by writing a PNG decoder which directly loads the image to , bypassing ImageSourceAndroid class.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old so probably few things changed, but if you are having image quality issues with WebView then consider converting your image into PNG format.

Somehow when I load the jpeg version of the image the quality is low, while loading the png image with the same resolution the quality is high.

Comment: Same quality result, for me, wether the extension is JPEG or PNG.