# Android WebView Image Quality for *SMALL Image*

Tags: android, image, webview

I have a jQuery Mobile web application which I am displaying in a web view. I don't use any images in it except whatever is default with jQM. I've created a very standard input element and as you know it renders with nice round fuzzy corners. jQM created these rounded corners with CSS if I recall correctly.

Scaling is disabled on the webview and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

What I've noticed is that the input elements look very jagged and pixelated. This behavior also occurs in the default browser. In firefox mobile and opera, I don't see this behavior and it renders the way it does on my PC. Is there any way to set the WV settings to render the CSS round corners properly?

On the left is webview. on the right is firefox:

[image: webview vs firefox rendering]

The check mark is just a background image in the input element.

---

Edit: Seems like Gingerbread and previous webviews don't support css3 anti aliasing. Ice Cream does support it though in my testing. What a bummer.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632140/android-pixel-quality-reduction-in-images-loaded-in-webview