# Drop large amount of data in browser and keep browser responsive?

Tags: javascript, performance, large-files

I am currently creating a webinterface where you can drag and drop images to.
After dropping the images, thumbnails are generated. Next you can select/delete/preview images before you choose to upload them to the server.

The interface should be able to handle large series of high quality images. Dropping 80 images of 5MB each is not supposed to be a problem.
Although when I drop a series of 20 images (about 5MB each) any browser will become irresponsive until all images are loaded (and thumbs generated) or the browser might even crash.

For those who want to give it a try:
http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~s0179967/webinterface/

Now is it possible to create such a web interface, which handles the data/images clientside, and keep the browser responsive, even when loading huge chunks of data?

EDIT: it are still the original 5MB images that need to be uploaded to the server.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905578/reading-large-images-as-thumbnails-locally-via-html5-filereader