# Filereader image thumbnail lags

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm using Filereader API to show little thumbnails of photo uploads. However I'm having a problem. When you upload really big images, and you upload a few of those, it starts to lag. The thumbnails are really small but the files are too big. Is there a way to fix this? Here's my javascript:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var files = e.target.files;

  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

    var f = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(tf){
      return function(evt){
        document.querySelector('.thumbs').innerHTML += '<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('+evt.target.result+')"></div>';
      }
    })(f);

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle where you can test it: https://jsfiddle.net/snx79yw2/1/.

For example, I tested it with 6000x4000 photos, and when there are more than 4, 5 they start to lag (and my PC is quite decent so it shouldn't lag like that).

BTW with lag I refer to slow down, freeze etc, not actual lag.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905578/reading-large-images-as-thumbnails-locally-via-html5-filereader) but I don't really know how to implement the solutions from that answer. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example resizes the images down to a max width of 127px using a Canvas before displaying them in the thumbnail list.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var files = e.target.files;
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    var f = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(tf) {
      return function(evt) {
        // resize the image before using the resolved dataURL to set the thumbnail src
        resize(evt.target.result, 127, function(dataURL) {
          document.querySelector('.thumbs').innerHTML += `<img class="thumb" src="${dataURL}" />`;
        });
      }
    })(f)

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
});
/**
* usage   resize( dataURL:src, int:maxWidth, function:callback)
*/
function resize(src, maxWidth, callback) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = () => {
      var oc = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = oc.getContext('2d');
      // resize to [maxWidth] px
      var scale = maxWidth / img.width;
      oc.width = img.width * scale;
      oc.height = img.height * scale;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
      // convert canvas back to dataurl
      callback(oc.toDataURL());
    }
}
```

```css
.thumbs{background: #222;border-radius: 5px;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: scroll;padding: .25rem;}
.thumb{height: 3rem;width: 3rem;border-radius: 3px;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;margin: .25rem .25rem calc(.25rem - 4px);}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple />
<div class="thumbs"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I've a few questions though: 1) Is it possible to change the scaling method (to remove aliassing) ? 2) I can't use ES6, are promises really neccesary? How can I work around them?

Comment: 2) Ive editied my answer to use a callback instead of a promise. 1) Probably, but I don't know enough about image processing to be able to come up with an answer here.

Comment: Thanks, I found one solution in here so I'm gonna blend in the two!